# URL not getting stored in a file

Tags: python

The URL is not getting stored in the file 'youtube_alarm_videos.txt'. The code seems fine to me, but it is not working. Can someone please help me with the error?
[Full code here](https://pastebin.com/sjMMS2pZ)

```
""" Alarm Clock
----------------------------------------

"""
import datetime
import os
import time
import random
import webbrowser
import winsound

# If video URL file does not exist, create one
url = print("Enter the link to the video below")
while True:
    url_input = input("Enter link:")
    break
else:
    print("Could not find the link entered. Please check and try again")
    
if not os.path.isfile("youtube_alarm_videos.txt"):
    with open("youtube_alarm_videos.txt", "w") as alarm_file:
        alarm_file.write(url_input)
```

Comment: Does the file `youtube_alarm_videos.txt` exist? If it does, the code after `if not os.path.isfile("youtube_alarm_videos.txt"):` won't be executed

Answer (score 1):

In the example you gave us there is much code that doesn't do anything.
I think you wanted to give the minimal reproducible example but kept code that doesn't do anything and/or deleted code that is relevant to your question.

For example:

```py
url = print("Enter the link to the video below")
```

print has no return value, so url would still be `None`.

```py
while True:
    url_input = input("Enter link:")
    break
else:
    print("Could not find the link entered. Please check and try again")
```

`input` will always execute, the `else` is dead code

If you want to append a link to the file, this code would be sufficient:

```py
url_input = input("Enter link:")
with open("youtube_alarm_videos.txt", "a") as alarm_file:
    alarm_file.write(f"{url_input}\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need somthing like this

```py
import datetime
import os
import time
import random
import webbrowser
import winsound

# If video URL file does not exist, create one

def create_file(filename="youtube_alarm_videos.txt"):
    # Create new file if doesn't exist
    with open(filename, 'w') as e:
        pass

url = print("Enter the link to the video below")
while True:
    url_input = input("Enter link:")
    break
else:
    print("Could not find the link entered. Please check and try again")
    
if os.path.isfile("youtube_alarm_videos.txt"):
    create_file()

with open("youtube_alarm_videos.txt", 'w') as e:
    e.write(url_input)
```